# Inside model allow user to update only one field while avoiding empty non-changed form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**What I need:** I have a groups table and for -certain- groups I want user to be able to update only the name attribute. While trying to update other attributes, page must flash an error message. I'd like to realise it in model-level.

**What I've done so far:** I thought about making `before_update` callback into my `Group` model that asks `@group.changed` and when it gets back an array that contains attributes user must not be able to update then model raises an error. I combined my existing solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051135/rails-3-check-if-attribute-changed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297506/update-attributes-for-user-only-if-attributes-have-changed) like this:

```
before_update :check_update_params

protected
  def check_update_params
    if self.only_name_update_allowed?
      changed = self.changed
      # I'd like to have somekind of empty-value check here
      # that ignores non-changed empty string and boolean-fields
      if changed.present? && changed != ["name", "updated_at"]
        raise I18n.t('my_app.groups.errors.only_name_update_available')
      end
    end
  end
```

**Problem:** Everything is ok except empty values interpreted differently in form and in db. If I log out the `changed` variable then I get an array that also includes some attributes that I didn't change in form but db interprets them as changed. That is due to the fact that form sends empty checkbox with a value of `0` which is saved in db as `false` but previous value in db was `nil`. Same problem is with text-fields- form form comes an empty string value like `""` but database has a value of `nil`.

Here are some illustrating **examples** of my empty-value problem:

```
irb(main):130:0* Group.all.each do |g|
irb(main):131:1* puts "name: #{g.name} my_boolean_attr: #{g.my_boolean_attr}"
irb(main):132:1> end
  Group Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"
name: group1 my_boolean_attr: 
name: group2 my_boolean_attr: 
name: group3 my_boolean_attr: 
name: group4 my_boolean_attr: 
name: group5 my_boolean_attr: 
name: group6 my_boolean_attr: false
name: group7 my_boolean_attr: false
name: group8 my_boolean_attr: false
name: group9 my_boolean_attr: false
```

Similar problem with text field:

```
irb(main):130:0* Group.all.each do |g|
irb(main):131:1* puts "name: #{g.name} my_string_attr: #{g.my_string_attr == ""}"
irb(main):132:1> end
  Group Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"
name: group1 my_string_attr: false
name: group2 my_string_attr: false
name: group3 my_string_attr: false
name: group4 my_string_attr: false
name: group5 my_string_attr: false
name: group6 my_string_attr: false
name: group7 my_string_attr: false
name: group8 my_string_attr: true
name: group9 my_string_attr: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already managed to solve my problem with little helper method inside my model which gets called from my callback-method. I also changed the callback from `before_update` to `before_validation` to avoid a situation where user must first deal with errors from validations and, when those fixed, sees that it was pointless because he could only change name anyway. The helper-method with callback looks now like this:

```
before_validation :check_update_params

protected

  def check_update_params
    if self.only_name_update_allowed?
      changed = self.update_corrections(self.changed)
      if changed.present? && !(changed == ["name"] || changed == ["name", "updated_at"])
        raise I18n.t('my_app.groups.errors.only_name_update_available')
      end
    end
  end

  def update_corrections(changed)
    unneccessary = []
    changed.each do |atr|
      # Avoid pointless updates:
      if (self.changes[atr] == [nil, false] || self.changes[atr] == [nil, ""])
        unneccessary << atr #
      end
    end
    changed - unneccessary
  end
```

Of course another solution would have been to set default values into the db from the start but that would have assumed that for ex there is no difference between `nil` and `false` regarding to boolean values.

**NB!** I'm still interested if there is a better solution for this!